# How to set the margin of backBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

How to set the margin of backBarButtonItem ?

Using these methods has no effect：

```
backItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 0)
backItem.width = 100
self.viewControllers.last?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Setting back BarButtonItem's left margin, the designer felt backBarButtonItem was too close to the left, and I didn't want to use leafBarButtonItem

Comment: I would use UIBarButtonItem.fixedSpace to create an item to sit between the back button and other items.

Comment: I'm using backBarButtonItem, not leafBarButtonItems, there's no way to add a UIBarButtonItem.fixedSpace